# SFTP/SCP when ultimate destination is a mapped fileshare. Is it secure for the entire end to end transfer?

Tags: windows, security, network-share, sftp, scp

I'm trying to securely transfer data from Solaris (version 10) to a Windows fileshare so the business users can access it.

The fileshare is mapped as a drive letter in an intermediary Windows Server (Win2003) that has openSSH running as a service.

If I use SFTP or SCP to PUSH the file from Solaris, I expect the transfer will be secure to the intermediary server - but will the transfer to the ultimate destination (the fileshare) be secure or is the final transmission done by Windows without encryption?

Comment: Only if the fileshare is securely mounted

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with SFTP/SCP, you should remove them from the tags and the title and simply ask if an access to a shared drive is secured or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows filesharing between the Windows Server and the clients will be done in the clear, without encryption.  If this part of the transfer needs to be secured, some other means needs to be implemented.  This can be done by having a VPN between the Windows Server and the clients (but then depending on the network topology) or by having all the files stored on the share being encrypted (for example by a solution like the [Symantec File Share Encryption](https://www.symantec.com/products/information-protection/encryption/file-share-encryption) or [Winmagic FFE](https://www.winmagic.com/products/features/ffe-file-encryption-folder-encryption)).

See also this other question: [Access Windows file share over the internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/267308/access-windows-file-share-over-the-internet) and some recommendations by Microsoft about EFS (Encrypting File System) and [Remote Storage of Encrypted Files Using SMB File Shares and WebDAV](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700811.aspx#XSLTsection129121120120).